# Set a private value in Azure Pipeline and integrate with TestCafe when running pipeline regression

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, ui-automation, testcafe

Currently, I'm using TestCafe to create automation test scripts and integrate CI/CD with the Azure pipeline. We need to login to the web to start testing.
I want to set a private value for the password in the pipeline and not in our source code. I have tried to research it and have created a private value password in the library pipeline.
But I don't know how to integrate it into our source code to get that password when logging into our system when running pipeline regression.

So have anyone has know about this or have any experience for that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.